# Обратиться напрямую к файлу в Wordpress

Tags: .htaccess, php, wordpress

Здравствуйте! Есть сайт на wordpress, достаточно много записей в БД, мне надо выполнить некоторые преобразования с БД, решил написать скрипт на php и тупо вызвать его, обратившись напрямую через адресную строку. Но чтобы я не делал, куда бы я его не ложил, (wp-content, wp-content/uploads и т.д.) прямое обращение невозможно. Т.е. открывается сайт с пустой страницей на которой написано что материал не найден или не существует. Я так полагаю что дело в настройках файла .htaccess, но что с ним делать понятия не имею. Вот код файла .htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/robots\.txt$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/vechernee_plate_moskva\.htm$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/vechernie_platya\.htm$
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}/tcategory/vechpl [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/gallery/xzotic\.htm [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/svadebnye_platya\.htm$
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/korotkie_svadebnye_platya\.htm$
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}/tcategory/korotkie [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

#<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$">
#   RewriteEngine On
#   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
#   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /watermark/watermark.php [T=application/x-httpd-php,L,QSA]
#</FilesMatch>
```

Что в нём надо поправить чтобы прямое обращение к файлам в корне сайта стало возможным. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А у вас правильная ссылка на файл?


Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну если нужно скрипт запустить всего один раз, закоментируйте (#) все записи в .htaccess и запускайте свой скрипт, потом раскомментируйте.

Comment: Не прокатило. =( может тут какая-то другая причина? Может копать не в сторону .htaccess ?

Comment: пишет вот что http://www.victoriya-salon.ru/up.php

Comment: Разобрался. Там хаос в фтп был, я тупо не в ту папку скрипт засовывал. Спасибо за помощь!